# animated menu closing/opening behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, menu

I am creating a website with a mobile menu. 
The menu button should be animated the menu should initially be hidden and open when pressing the button. 
It should also close and animate to the original state when either clicking the button again, or a link in it. 
Right now I have several problems with my code: 
1. Menu is open when I load the page
2. Menu doesn't close when clicking a link

The code is from a real website so all the links direct you to a subpage which doesn't exist in jsfiddle. I prepared the link "Club" so that it doesn't redirect you
https://jsfiddle.net/TheBB23/nmobt0c7/2/

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("hamburger");


var hideLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.mobilemenuitems a');



var i;





for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var mobilemenuitems = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (mobilemenuitems.style.display === "block") {
      mobilemenuitems.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      mobilemenuitems.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
var header = document.querySelector(".header");
// On click
hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Toggle class "is-active"
  hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");
  header.classList.toggle("header--is-active");
  // Do something else, like open/close menu
});
```

```css
/* Responsive (Smartphone) Menu */
@media (max-width: 1000px) {

  .nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #24603c;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
  }



  #BurgerSpace>div>button {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
  }

  #BurgerSpace>div>div {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  #BurgerSpace {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: -2px;
  }
}

.mobilemenuspace {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: pink;
}




.hamburger {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.hamburger:hover .hamburger-inner::after {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.hamburger:hover .hamburger-inner::before {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.hamburger:hover .hamburger-inner {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.hamburger-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger-inner {
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
  width: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.hamburger-inner::before {
  top: -10px;
}

.hamburger-inner::after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

.hamburger--collapse .hamburger-inner {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.13s;
  transition-delay: 0.13s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hamburger--collapse .hamburger-inner::after {
  top: -20px;
  transition: top 0.2s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1), opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.hamburger--collapse .hamburger-inner::before {
  transition: top 0.12s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1), transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hamburger--collapse.is-active .hamburger-inner {
  transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
  transition-delay: 0.22s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.hamburger--collapse.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333), opacity 0.1s 0.22s linear;
}

.hamburger--collapse.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: top 0.1s 0.16s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333), transform 0.13s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.header--is-active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

</div>

<div id="BurgerSpace">
  <div class="header">
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button">
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
    </button>

    <div class="mobilemenuspace">
      <div class="mobilemenuitems">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <h2> Login</h2>

        <li>
          <a href="#">CLUB</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*kontakt">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*vorstand">Vorstand</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*mitgliedsantrag">Mitgliedschaft</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*ueber_uns">Über uns</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=*Hockey">HOCKEY</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*1.Herren">1. Herren</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*1.Damen">1. Damen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">Jugend <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul class="menulist">
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Jugend">Jugend</a>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MJA">Männliche Jugend A</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MJB">Männliche Jugend B</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnA">A Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnB">B Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnC">C Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnD">D Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnE">E Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*WJA">Weibliche Jugend A</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*WJB">Weibliche Jugend B</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaA">A Mädchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaB">B Mädchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaC">C Mädchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaD">D Mädchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaE">E Mädchen</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Erwachsene">Erwachsene</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Trainingsplan">Trainingsplan</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Schiedsrichter">Schiedsrichter</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Links">offizielle Links</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=events_gruppe&id=975">Kalender</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=*Tennis">TENNIS</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Herren">HERREN</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Damen">DAMEN</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Jugend">JUGEND</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Trainer">TRAINER</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Schule">TENNISSCHULE</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*_action_events_gruppe_id_976">KALENDER</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=platzbuchung_woche&id=117">PLATZBUCHUNG</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Links">OFFIZIELLE LINKS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=*UhlenTV">UHLEN.TV</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=profile">MEIN.HTCU</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_edit">PROFIL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=start_news&cmd=list">ARTIKEL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_meinerechnungen">Meine Rechnungen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_mitgliedsbescheinigung">Meine Mitgliedsbescheinigung</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_teilnahmebescheinigung">Meine Teilnahmebescheinigungen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_interessen">Meine Interessen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=events_meinetermine">Meine Termine</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_wunschmeine">Meine Support-Anfragen</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=admin">ADMIN</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">KASSE <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul class="menulist">
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?module=kasse">KASSE</a>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_tasks">Startseite</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_beleg">SPESEN</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Belege <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchung&cmd=addmulti">Belegschnellerfassung</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_angebote">Angebote</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_rechnungneu">Neue Rechnung</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=members_beitragaktuell">BEITRÄGE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Rechnungen <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=0">Rechnungen unverschickt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=1">Rechnungen offen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=2">Rechnungen in Bezahlung</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=3">Rechnungen bezahlt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=6">Rechnungen alle</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_faellig">Übersichten</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_einzug">SEPA-ÜW/Einzug</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Buchführung <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_journal">Journal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_guv">Gewinn und Verlust</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_bilanzoffenk">Übersichten</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_kontenrahmen">Kontenrahmen</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Barkasse <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_barkasse&konto=1000">Hauptkasse</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Bankkonten <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_kontouebersicht">(Übersicht)</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_bank&bankkonto=250">Vereinskonto Sparkasse</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_overview">ÜBERBLICK</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_basis">BASISKONFIG</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_optionen">OPTIONEN</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel1">
              <a href="#">VORLAGEN <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul class="menulist">
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=admin_mailtemplates">MAIL</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=admin_pdftemplates">PDF</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=admin_static">HTML</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=admin_antraege">Anträge</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_wunsch">Support-Anfragen</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>




      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) If the menu is open when the page is called, you may want to hide it until called using `style="display: none;"` on the `mobilespacemenu`-class.
**Edit:** If you really want to use JS to hide the menu on page load, you could use: 
 `document.onload = document.getElementsByClassName("mobilemenuspace")[0].style.display = "none";`, although referencing using an Id might be a better option [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cz6hbnp7/1/).

2.) Add an EventListener to the div, reacting on clicks and hiding the menu.

I am not quite sure whether [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cz6hbnp7/) covers all points (and if I determined the menu correctly).

Comment: One thing is unfortunately not working with your approach: If you click a link in the menu the menu closes but the animated button does not change. So the button looks like the menu is open but it isn't.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Just add `hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");` to the close-function like in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zo1vk6qe/) example.